# Column color based when ploting a GeoDataFrame with 'explore' method

Tags: python, colors, geopandas, folium

I'd like to **color** the cities that belongs to one **hemisphere** or another with the color specified at 'Color' column. All the cities of each hemisphere (each category) have the same value for that **column**. I'd like the legend to show the same colors too.

I'm not being able of getting it. Could anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Note: This is a reproducible example of what I'm dealing with -based on geopandas examples.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
gdf['Hemisphere'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: 'Norte'if x.y > 0 else 'Sur')
gdf['Color'] = gdf['Hemisphere'].apply(lambda x: '#D94325' if x=='Norte' else '#5CD925')

gdf.explore(column='Hemisferio', color='Color')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's a simple case of defining your own color map
- FYI I have just created a PR to provide more flexibility https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2354

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.colors as colors

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
gdf['Hemisphere'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: 'Norte'if x.y > 0 else 'Sur')
gdf.explore(column='Hemisphere', cmap=colors.ListedColormap(['#D94325','#5CD925']))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh great! Thank you very much! Since it works the same as 'plot' method, this also answers this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/417574/194341
I invite you to answer it too :)

Comment: registered and answered...